# Duas operações de query numa collection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Sou novo em Node JS e mongoDB e estou a tentar executar um `find` e em seguida um `update`, mas parece não está a ser possível. Alguém tem uma ideia?

```
function CarrinhoDAO(conexao) {
    this._conexao = conexao();
}

CarrinhoDAO.prototype.retira = function(res, email_cliente, id_produto, retira) {
    this._conexao.open(function(erro, mongocliente) {
        mongocliente.collection("carrinhos", function(erro, collection) {
            collection.find({
                $and: [
                    { cliente: email_cliente },
                    { estado: "aberto" },
                    { lista_compras: { $size: 1 } }
                ]
            }).toArray(function(erro, qtd) {
                if (qtd.length == 1){
                     collection.update({
                    $and: [
                        { cliente: email_cliente },
                        { estado: "aberto" }
                    ]
                }, {
                    $pull: { lista_compras: { id_produto_carrinho: objectId(id_produto) } },
                    $unset: { supermercado: 1 }
                }, function(erro, records) {
                    if (erro) {
                        res.end(erro);
                    } else {
                        res.json(records);
                    }
                });
                }
            });
        }
}
```

O resultado a obter do `find` depende da execução ou não do `update`.

Answer (score -1):

voce pode utilizar :
[db.collection.findOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

```
retira.findOneAndUpdate({age: 17}, {$set:{name:"Naomi"}}, 
{new: true}, function(err, doc){
if(err){
    console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
}

console.log(doc);});
```